# How To Highlight Show Active Tab In A Navbar-Fixed-Top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am current changing a website to use Bootstrap and I have been advised that they want to use the `navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top` main menu.

The thing is I can't figure out how to highlight the selected page and keep it highlighted.

I have tried the follow Jquery but I cant get none of them working

```
 $(function() {
    $('#nav li a').click(function() {
       $('#nav li').removeClass();
       $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');
    });
 });
```

My HTML for my menu is:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Logo Here</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
                    <li style="border-left: 1px solid lightgray"><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                    <li style="border-left: 1px solid lightgray"><a runat="server" href="~/Session/pg1">Session</a></li>
                    <li style="border-left: 1px solid lightgray"><a runat="server" href="~/EmailPg">Email</a></li>
                </ul>
                <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would prefer if its possible to do it with CSS or Jquery but I was also a little confused as, do I add the Jquery to every page OR can I add one lot to my Site.Master file

Comment: Are you using a single file for menu then include in all file? Is that right?

Comment: @MHK My menu is sat in my Site.Master it that's what you are meaning

Comment: Your page reload when you click at the nav link? What happens when you click the link? Are you using MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding the below JQuery to my Site.Master file

```
var url = window.location;
// Will only work if string in href matches with location
$('ul.nav a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

// Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
$('ul.navbar-nav a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not selecting the active `li` tag correctly.

Instead I suggest you use something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav li a').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('li') // select the parent <li> tag
        .addClass('active')// add the active class
        .siblings() // select the siblings of the active tag
        .removeClass('active'); // remove the active class from the other <li>
    });
});
```

Comment: Your suggestion still doesn't work for me.  I have added the code you provided to my 'About' page but it doesn't stay highlighted. I also tried adding `class="active"` to my homepage `<li>` but that doesn't work either

Comment: I'm a little confused.  What exactly does your suggestion do? as you aren't able to click on the menu links as the options don't work, well they don't for me anyway.  I can get the menu option to highlight fine, just not stay selected when on the page.  Where do I put this code as I have tried on the page itself and also in my Site.Master as I said it doesn't seem to work for me